# error while loading shared libraries: libInventor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am Trying to execute a Visual aplication, but I got the next message:

> ./track: error while loading shared libraries: libInventor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I execute "ldd" command and I got these message:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
        libInventor.so => not found
        libInventorXt.so => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76cf000)
        libsfbcomm.so => not found
        librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf76c5000)
        libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib32/libxvidcore.so.4 (0xf75e2000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf74eb000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf74c5000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf74a8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7363000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7721000)
```

How can I to assign the files not found? And also I have to change from libInventorXt.so to libInventorQt.so, How can I do that?
I am not root

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the packages that contain libInventor and so on.  You can use aptitude or apt-file to find which package you need:

```
$ apt-file search libInventor.so
inventor-dev: /usr/lib/libInventor.so
libinventor0: /usr/lib/libInventor.so.0
libinventor0: /usr/lib/libInventor.so.0.0.0
$ apt-get install inventor-dev
```

Should do the trick.  Ditto with the rest of the libraries.  Clearly installing your programme with apt-get would be ideal if there were a package for it under Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I forget tell that I have the Inventor library installed, but it is installed in /usr/include/Inventor, I think that I only need the soname libInventor.so, but I dont know how can I make the soname..

Comment: In that case you need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables and add /usr/include/Inventor/lib/ or where ever the library is installed. However, I would recommend against install things manually on a Ubuntu system. Please use the packaging system provided, in the long run it will save you hours of hassle.

Comment: I would like to know How can I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH , because I cant install anything because I have no authorization to do so,

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library/directory/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I introduce this: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/include/Inventor/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH since the sell, but I get the same error: ./track: error while loading shared libraries: libInventor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Make sure that you have the library libInventor.so in the path you added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Check that ldd can now find the library.

Comment: Tanks for help, I look for the library on the way you told me..I got this libInventor.so => not found
        libInventorXt.so => not found
I dont have the soname (libInventor.so) but I have a Inventor folder with the libraries of my program...I think that I only need the soname, but I dont know exactly how can I get it..

Comment: You need to either install a package or compile the library from source and install that in a path that is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  If you do not have root access, please ask your system administrator to do that for you.

Comment: Thank you for all your help..I think that now I can solve the problem